# How is the plus operator works in case of calculating integer with object?

Tags: java, oop, object, integer

guys!

How is the operator + implemented and works in Java internally in case when we add integer with Integer object?

```
package ru.systemres.ru;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer iOb = new Integer(10);
        int a = iOb + 5;
        System.out.println(a);

    }
}
```

Is it overloaded? Can you show me some source code from jvm which works with it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Autoboxing** is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper classes.

***During Unboxing*** 
(Object(Integer) --to--> Primitive(int))

Implicitly `Integer.intValue()` is called to return int value.

Please Refer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Comment: Ok, but how does it work internally step by step? Do we change + operator logic depending of the types on the left and on the right param? Or the Integer object behaves differently depending on the parameter? How does it work?

Comment: Autoboxing mainly occur in two places one is during assignment and other is during method invocation. In your case the variable is stored in primitive int a. So, the compiler is expecting primitive type here and converts the object to int in order to use it.


`//Internal Working`
`Integer obj = Integer.valueOf(10);`
`int pri = obj.intValue();`

Answer (score 0):

`iOb` isn't just any old object - it's an `Integer`. When you use it in such a context, it's [outboxed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) to an `int`, and then the calculation is performed.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it overloaded? Can you show me some source code from jvm which
>   works with it?

It is NOT overloaded, rather the `Integer` `iOb` object will be unboxed to `int` first and then added with `5` to the variable `a`.

I suggest you refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) for Autoboxing and Unboxing in Java.